# Adding multiple files to S3 with Amplify's Storage.put

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, amazon-s3, async-await, aws-amplify

**Expectations:**

The input element accepts multiple image files, and `AWS-Amplify's` asynchronous `Storage.put()` adds them to the preconfigured S3 bucket.

**Problem**

I have attempted a solution of using a `for in` loop, but it seems to be skipping over the `try catch` blocks.

**Input Element**

```
            <input
              type="file"
              hidden
              multiple
              accept="image/*"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
```

**`OnChange` Function**

```
  async function onChange(e) {
    try {
      for (const file of e.target.files) {
        console.log("Start of Loop")
        await Storage.put(file.name, file, {
          metadata: [
            { name: file.name },
            { lastModifiedDate: file.lastModifiedDate },
            { type: file.type },
          ],
          level: "protected",
          contentType: "image/*",
        });
        console.log("End of for loop");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error uploading file: ", error);
    }
  }
```

**Console.logs()**

[image: Console.logs]

Link to Amplify's `Storage.put()` information: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to upload multiple files to S3.

**The front-end component from Mui:**

```
      <Button
        size={"large"}
        component="label"
        variant={"outlined"}
        sx={{ marginTop: { xs: 2, md: 0 } }}
      >
        <input
          type="file"
          hidden
          multiple
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        Upload
      </Button>
```

**The `for in loop` needed:**

```
  async function onChange(e) {
      for (const file of e.target.files) {
        Storage.put(file.name, file, {
          level: "protected",
          contentType: "image/*",
        })
          .then((result) => console.log(result))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));;
        console.log("End of for loop");
      }
  }
```

To read more about how `Storage.put()` works, go to this link: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js/